# In a Ruby gem, is it possible to have executables written in other languages?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem which has an executable in `bin/`. A wildcard is used in the gemspec:

```
s.executables = Dir["bin/*"].map &File.method(:basename)
```

If I have a ruby file at `bin/my_file` which had `chmod a+x` run, then it's found in the PATH in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "working ruby script"
```

However I have another executable written in coffeescript at `bin/my_file.coffee`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
console.dir "printing from coffee file"
```

When I run `my_file.coffee` in shell, it tries to read this script with ruby instead of coffeescript.

How can I run this executable with coffeescript as intended?

As it stands, I'm using a workaround which is to wrap my coffee code as a string in my ruby app and then passing it to `coffee -e` and capturing the output.

Also, looking at [this RubyGems issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/830) shows the official explanation:

> RubyGems is not meant to support arbitrary executables.

OK. So is there an alternative besides wrapping code in heredoc?

Is there a good reason this restriction is in place?

Comment: how do you run your coffee file? if you use `bundle exec` it will use ruby, of course.

Comment: `When I run my_file.coffee in shell, it tries to read this script with ruby instead of coffeescript.` This doesn't make sense. What happens when you're in bin, `my_file.coffee` has `u+x` and you run `./my_file.coffee`? It shouldn't have to do anything with Ruby.

Comment: Your question implies that the shebang at the top of of the executable is completely ignored by the Linux shell during execution, which I find difficult to believe (similar to what @EricDuminil is saying). I think there is some missing info here.

Comment: @MarianTheisen I am not using bundle exec. The file is at `bin/test.coffee` and after I run `gem install <my_gem>`, as expected it is in my PATH and I can just say `test.coffee` in shell.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ruby gems have a way to ship executables, but it appears it isn't supported for languages other than ruby. When I run it like `./my_file.coffee` it does work. But using a relative path doesn't work when distributing a gem.

Comment: @MattSchuchard i think that is what is happening. see the rubygems issue i linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's simply in the specification of RubyGems:

https://github.com/zzak/rubygems/commit/709c5aae7ffd9958cc2ea89dc2caf6b7e02c56b7

```
+  # Executables included may only be ruby scripts, not scripts for other
+  # languages or compiled binaries.
+  #
```